# Design pattern to support last-in callbacks (e.g. handling hashchange)

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my web page, I have multiple independent plug-ins (for lack of a better word) that all interact with the `location.hash` of the browser. (I have a bit of code that keeps their work separated, but that's irrelevant to this question.) For example, I have:

```
// file1.js
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){ ... } );

// file2.js
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){ ... } );
```

The above works as desired when the hash changes after the page loads. However, I also need this code to process whatever hash the page initially loads with. If I write this code:

```
// file1.js
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){ ... } ).trigger('hashchange');

// file2.js
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){ ... } ).trigger('hashchange');
```

...then the first set of code will be run twice. Not desirable.

What's a good pattern for triggering the `hashchange` event only once, after all event handlers have been put in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to separate the handling code out into a separate function for each file and invoke just that code, explicitly:

```
// file1.js
function doStuff1(){ ... };
$(window).bind('hashchange',doStuff1);
doStuff1();

// file2.js
function doStuff2(){ ... };
$(window).bind('hashchange',doStuff2);
doStuff2();
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to namespace the event handlers and triggers:

```
// file1.js
$(window).bind('hashchange.file1', function(){...} ).trigger('hashchange.file1');

// file2.js
$(window).bind('hashchange.file2', function(){...} ).trigger('hashchange.file2');
```

This will cause both handlers to run whenever a generic `hashchange` event really occurs, but only cause the namespaced handler to run when triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
// file1.js
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){ ... } )

// file2.js
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){ ... } )

// Actual page
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

Comment: A reasonable suggestion, so +1. However, I like writing plug-ins that work by themselves upon inclusion; this answer requires a little extra work by the consumer of the plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this work?

```
function doStuff(){

    //run some code only on the first execution
    alert('execute miscellaneous code once on load');


    function myHandler(){
        alert('myHandler fired');
    }


    //or just execute the function that gets returned below
    myHandler();

    // return myHandler as the event handler
    return myHandler;

};

$(window).bind('hashchange', doStuff() );
```

This gives you the flexibility to treat the initial load differently than subsequent `hashchange` events.

**Update:**

Changed the above code sample. [Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bryandowning/msmvp/)

Answer (score 0):

Our web app is as well based on various plugins in a page, and use the # key for its state.

But not at the plugin level.
The code below is a portion of the main js file of the app.
It is run once at parsing time.

```
var hashChanged = function(){
    //action to do when the # changed
    $b.pub( ... );
};
/* avoid an error on older browsers */
if('onhashchange' in window){
    window.onhashchange = hashChanged;
}
//start the app, the same way as an # change
hashChanged();
```

The `$b.pub` is a kind of [pub/sub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe) eventing to tell the plugins what to do.